# How can I have a View vertically fill the space of a ScrollView in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have:

```
            <ScrollView style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, height: '100%', paddingTop: 250, left: 0, right: 0, marginBottom: -50, backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: customTheme.colors.background, paddingHorizontal: 5 }}>
                    <Title>{conversation?.title}</Title>
                    {participants.length > 0 && <List.Item
                        title={<ParticipantAvatarRow participants={participants} />}
                        description={`${participants.length} people joining`}
                        left={props => <FontAwesome {...props} style={{ marginVertical: 5 }} name='group' size={24} />}
                    />}
```

But the `View` doesn't fill the vertical space of `ScrollView`. I want it to be at least as much as `ScrollView`, but possibly more if the content stretches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much sense in filling a `ScrollView` vertically with a `View` component which will eventually stretch more if there is more content to show, simply having multiple components inside a `ScrollView` should in theory do exactly what you're expecting, no need for a wrapping `View`. Unless you're trying to achieve something special that I didn't yet consider.

With that being said, if you **really** need to have this wrapping `View` with a dynamic minimum height, I would suggest using the `height` value from `react-native Dimensions` component like so:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

This will give you exactly the device's height that you can use to stretch your `View`. If your `ScrollView` is not the same height as the device's (for instance when having top/bottom navigation bars and safe area insets, then you could use the height of these components and subtract from the device's `height` value before passing it to the `View` component style.

This would make sure that the `View` showing up inside the `ScrollView` has a dynamic and hard-coded `height` value which suits for all devices.